# Having a file open automatically when the compressed folder containing it is unzipped

Tags: windows, compression, kml, unzip, google-earth

I have a compressed (zipped) folder with several KML files and some image files in it. I will soon make the compressed folder available to download from a web site; once the site's user downloads the file, they can unzip it. I am wondering if there is a way to make a certain one of the KML files open in Google Earth automatically as soon as the folder is unzipped (this file is linked to the other KML files in the folder, and opening it in Google Earth is a much handier way of viewing all the KML files than opening each file individually). Is there any way of implementing this? The operating system on my machine is Windows 7, in case this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The act of unzipping a .zip file cannot easily be triggered to open a particular file as you describe on the file system. You would need a drop-box like mechanism with a custom application waiting for new contents in a particular folder.

However, [KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) is a zipped file which when opened by Google Earth will display the root-level KML file (typically named doc.kml) so a workable solution would be to create a single KMZ file with folder-structure as needed. The KMZ file would include a parent KML with links to the sub-KML files either as [anchor links](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#featureanchor) (or feature anchor) accessed via feature [description](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description) and/or as [network links](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink).

The parent KML file can have in its top-level KML element an description with an index or table of contents with links to all the sub-KML files.

A working example of a feature-anchor can be found here:
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/feature-anchor/feature-anchor-semi.kmz

A good description of feature anchors in action with examples can be found in Chapter 2 of the [KML Handbook](http://www.informit.com/store/kml-handbook-geographic-visualization-for-the-web-9780321525598).